# Find combination of all float values rounded up and down in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

So I have a logical problem here and I am not able to solve it. So basically I need to find the combination of all float numbers present in an array, both rounded up and down.

For example, I have this array [2.5,1.3].
So the combination I need is [3,2][3,1][2,2][2,1] (So in the first array, both the values are rounded up, in second, the first value is rounded up and the second is rounded down, in the third, first value is rounded down and the second is rounded up, and in the fourth, both are rounded down).

As another example, imagine I have [4.5,1.7,3.4]
So the result should be: [4,2,4][4,1,4][4,1,3][5,1,3][5,1,4][5,2,4][5,2,3] and so on,

I have to do this for n number of elements and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the attempts you've made so we can help you, rather than writing your code for you.

Comment: You need nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the array elements, the inner loop alternates between call `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get an array of arrays with the up and down rounded values and get the cartesian product of it.

```js
const
    getCeilFloor = array => array.map(v => ['ceil', 'floor'].map(k => Math[k](v))),
    getCartesian = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));


getCartesian(getCeilFloor([2.5, 1.3])).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
getCartesian(getCeilFloor([4.5, 1.7, 3.4])).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```